# what is the limit value in LINEOUT -TI LCDK C6748

Tags: c, code-composer

I work in Code Composer Studio Version: 6.0.1.00040 with the card LCDK C6748.

In this card there is LINE_OUT for sampling out audio into speakers.

My question arises, because I encountered some phenomena that look like I reached a limit value when I assigened a value to LINE_OUT:

```
codec_data.channel[LEFT]= (uint16_t)outputLeft_referenceSignal; 
// this union is where I have to "place" the audio sample I create,
// but I suspect outputLeft_referenceSignal exceed the limit value
```

When it happens it sounds, like a cracked "PACK" in the speakers and then the expected audio signal is not played

Comment: generally, to output audio, the appropriate peripherals need to be initialized/programed.  amongst those peripherals are the EDMA, the McASP, the AIC31.  If those are not setup correctly, no audio signal will be output.  Also, The TI website has complete code examples.  Spectrum Digital has complete code examples, the E2E forum (run by TI) has people that are very familiar with the specific board/DSP and with audio signal handling using that DSP/board.  The code package (a CD) that comes with the board also has complete examples for audio, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The T.I. has complete code examples on how to handle each of the built-in peripherals of the C6847 DSP.

I strongly suggest you start searching/reading the T.I. web site for info on the C6748 DSP

amongst other things, like initializing the DSP, you need to understand the usage of the McASP and the AIC31 peripherals.

It is not a simple write to a I/O address.

If you have setup the above peripherals, please post the relevant code so we can determine the underlying problem.